# Synchronize two SQL Server database using Dotmim sync framework

Tags: c#

I have a WinForms database driven application that I want to make it work in online/offline mode using **Dotmim** sync framework that I find an article by their author [here](https://dev.to/mimetis/how-to-synchronize-relational-databases-with-dotmim-sync-5693?signin=true).

The documentation for the library is [here](https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/index.html)

this is my code to sync the two SQL Server databases one is **localdb** and the other one is now on the **SQL Server Management Studio** for the testing purpose:

```
            string connect = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=bright_square_db;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=D:\Folder\project_file\bright_square_db.mdf";

            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlSyncProvider serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(constring);
            SqlSyncProvider clientProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(connect);

            SyncAgent agent = new SyncAgent(clientProvider, serverProvider, new string[] { "I have listed all the tables here" });

            var progress = new SynchronousProgress<ProgressArgs>(s => MessageBox.Show($"{s.Context.SyncStage}:\t{s.Message}"));
            var syncContext = await agent.SynchronizeAsync(progress);

            MessageBox.Show(syncContext.ToString());
```

But, when I try to run the code. I am getting this error[image]

The columns that indicated in the error are for a table that created by the sync process named "scope_info" inside the SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by swapping the client and server connection string link in the third and fourth line of the above code. I don't know what exactly cause the problem, but lastly this changed makes the code work for me.